# AutoHotkey: trigger hotkey just with Alt and Window

Tags: autohotkey

I want a hotkey to trigger when I press only ALT+WIN, and then release.  So if I use those keys to modify a different hotkey (for example, `!#A`), I do NOT want it to trigger. Only if I press `!#` then release without another keypress.

I tried `!# UP::DoMyThing()`, but that didn't work.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Control/Alt/Shift, there is no generic/neutral **"Win" key** because the OS does not support it. (See [Modifier_keys](http://ahkscript.org/docs/KeyList.htm#Modifier_keys))

Furthermore "#" is the **modifier** symbol for the windows key. Modifier symbols are used only in key-combinations in order to modify other keys.

Try also

```
 !LWin UP::DoMyThing()
```

or

```
 !RWin UP::DoMyThing()
```